# Get pixel dimensions of a PNG on my Mac?

Tags: macos, images, png

I have a random `.PNG` file on my Mac.  Actually I have about a hundred of them.  What is the easiest way to get the pixel dimensions?  (I.e, 100 pixels wide and 50 high, or whatever).

Comment: Doesn't that just show up when you view the file properties?

Comment: I right click, then click "Get info", and don't see it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Terminal, you can use the following:

```
$ sips -g pixelWidth Pictures/238337225.png 
/Users/danielbeck/Pictures/238337225.png
  pixelWidth: 1140
$ sips -g pixelHeight Pictures/238337225.png 
/Users/danielbeck/Pictures/238337225.png
  pixelHeight: 900
```

To extract the value only, use e.g.

```
$ sips -g pixelHeight Pictures/238337225.png | tail -n1 | cut -d" " -f4
900
```

To embed that in AppleScript:

> `set h to do shell script "sips -g pixelHeight /Users/danielbeck/Pictures/238337225.png | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f4"`
>   `set w to do shell script "sips -g pixelWidth /Users/danielbeck/Pictures/238337225.png | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f4"`
>   `display alert "Height: " & (h as text) & "`
>   `Width: " & (w as text)`

Result:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can read the Spotlight metadata:

```
mdls Pictures/238337225.png | grep kMDItemPixel
kMDItemPixelCount              = 1026000
kMDItemPixelHeight             = 900
kMDItemPixelWidth              = 1140
```

To get the names and dimensions of all files in a directory:

```
$ mdls Pictures/* | grep "\(kMDItemDisplayName\|mMDItemPixel\)"
[...]
kMDItemDisplayName             = "url.png"
kMDItemPixelCount              = 16384
kMDItemPixelHeight             = 128
kMDItemPixelWidth              = 128
[...]
```

Or alternatively, using `find` and `sips`:

> `find /Users/danielbeck/Pictures -type f -name "*.png" -exec sips -g pixelWidth {} \; -exec sips -g pixelHeight {} \;`

---

More more flexibility, wrap in a shell script:

```
$ cat dim.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename=$1

if [ ! -f "$filename" ] ; then
    echo "$filename not found!";
    exit 1
fi

h=$( mdls "$filename" | grep kMDItemPixelHeight | tail -n1 | cut -d= -f2 )
w=$( mdls "$filename" | grep kMDItemPixelWidth | tail -n1 | cut -d= -f2 )

osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to {activate, display alert \"$filename\\nWidth:$w\\nHeight:$h\"}"
```

Result after `chmod +x dim/sh`:

```
$ ./dim.sh Pictures/flying_cars.png
```

[image]

---

You could easily extend the script to display dimensions for multiple files at once, or e.g. all png files in a certain directory. Output is as Finder dialog, so you can embed it into an Automator service:

Open *Automator* and select to create a *Service* that receives *image files* as input in *any application*.

Add a *Run Shell Script* action that receives input *as arguments* and enter the following:

```
dlg=
for f in "$@"
do
    h=$( mdls "$f" | grep kMDItemPixelHeight | tail -n1 | cut -d= -f2 )
    w=$( mdls "$f" | grep kMDItemPixelWidth | tail -n1 | cut -d= -f2 )
    dlg="$dlg$f\nW:$w H:$h\n"
done
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to {activate, display alert \"$dlg\"}"
exit 0
```

Save as *Show Image Dimensions*. Select a few image files in Finder and select *Finder » Services » Show Image Dimensions* or `Right-click` on one of the files and *[Services »] Show Image Dimensions*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oldie, but still a goodie!

Comment: Nice. But sips doesn't directly have a single-line syntax to return `width x height` ?

Answer (score 8):

Find the file in a Finder window, and either:

- Highlight the file and press <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, or
- Control-click the file and hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> so you can select "Show Inspector".

This will open an inspector which is similar to the Get Info window, but updates each time you select a file.

Now expand the "More info" section on the inspector. You will be able to see the PNG's dimensions and color depth, among other data. Select a new file to see its dimensions in the inspector.

[image: An inspector window showing the highlighted file in a Finder window]

Comment: The weird thing is that when I open that window, what I see under "more info" is Title, Headline, and Last Opened . . . but no dimensions, color space, color profile, or alpha channel.  My OS is 10.6.7 and my Finder is version 10.6.8; could that be the problem?

Comment: This feature depends on Spotlight to index the image's location. Are the picture in a non-indexed location?

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but for current readers, there is now a readily available solution.  In Yosemite, you can turn on the "Show Preview Column" in Finder. Finder > View > Show View Options

Here's a screenshot.

[image: screenshot].

Comment: sadly the question was posted in 2011 and yosemite was released in 2014

Comment: yeah, it was the number 1 search result when i looked for answer to this problem on Google, so i thought others would benefit from my answer

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way; open the images in Safari.

Select all the images. Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click context menu and choose **Open With > Safari**.

Optionally you can merge all the open Safari menus together into separate tabs using the Safari menu **Window > Merge All Windows**.

The top of the Safari window displays the image dimensions:
[image]

Comment: I find it **really** bizarre that this is the only option that worked for me. Why do I have to open a browser to view picture dimensions ?!? This is ridiculous. Thanks for the answer nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use the Finder add a separate 'Dimensions' and 'Resolution' column to the list view of a folder.

- Open your Pictures folder. */Users/~/Pictures*
- Create a new folder within the opened Pictures folder. *Do not drag one in from elsewhere.*
- In this new folder, in list view, right/option-click the column header row.
- Check both of the options available at the bottom of the contextual
  menu, 'Dimensions' and 'Resolution'.

Now the nice part.

- Drag this new folder onto the desktop (or wherever) and open.
- Note that the modified header row retains the headers 'Dimensions'
  and 'Resolution'.
- Add images files to the folder and in list view read the dimensions
  and resolutions info for all the image files at once and not one at a
  time with the various info panel methods.

Sometimes Resolution is not calculated or available and a dash will appear in the column. See attachment.

This still works as of macOS Sierra 10.12.6
I do not know if this folder setting sticks when the folder is moved to another user account, network folder, etc.

[**Screenshot: Folder in list view with Dimension and Resolution columns.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX29N.png)

Answer (score -1):

Open the image in preview then go to tools>Show Inspector(⌘S). This will bring up a window that displays the image dimensions with pixels as the unit.