# Export layers as images with TXT info file about each exported image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, gimp

Exporting layers to images in both Photoshop and Gimp is easy.

But is there a way that any of these tools create a TXT file for **each exported image** which would contain some information about exported image? One txt file for each exported image.

Information I am talking about is size and resolution (and so on). Ideally the script would export these information in a structured file like

```
<size></size>
<resolution></resolution>
```

Is this possible? I am guessing someone must have had written such add-on.

Comment: Couldn't you extract this information from the exported image files? Or is any of this information only available in the source file(s)?

Comment: @DanielBeck Extract manually? That is too slow and too many images.

Comment: No, using a script similar to what I provided [in this question](http://superuser.com/a/273098) which could trivially be adapted to add a text file per image file containing the desired information (if available in the exported images at all) instead of opening a dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can do it with Photoshop scripting (javascript). Here is an [example of a script](https://github.com/omgmog/photoshop-text-export/blob/master/Text%20Export.jsx) that exports to a text file. Exporting the images and collecting the data on dimensions etc is also supported.

References to get you started in the world of Photoshop scripting:

- [Photoshop scripting guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf)
- [Photoshop JS Scripting Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the excellent exiftool and using a command to do this. This command creates a txt file for each image file in the folder. You could of course include a lot more meta data than resolution and size.

```
exiftool.exe -ImageSize -FileSize pathFolderWithImages -w .txt
```

You could even get the output as one json (or xml or html) file per folder with this:

```
exiftool.exe -ImageSize -FileSize -json pathFolderWithImages > data.js
```

Get the tool and learn more about [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).